# How to deliver email to a specific server address? (gmail, office365)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mailkit, mimekit

**Hello there!**

I've built an email parser, to act as an email security gateway. 
My domain has had its MX records changed to deliver emails to the parser.

Behind the scenes, I am still using Gmail, and now I wish to deliver the parsed emails to my inbox. However, I can't seem to figure out where to specify a specific delivery address. (this MX record isn't present on my domain, naturally)

For Gmail, you need to deliver emails to: 
`ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.` , and I need to use my own SMTP server to deliver it after scanning it with the parser.

This is the current standard code, using MailKit:

```
// Compose a message
MimeMessage mail = new MimeMessage();
mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Excited Person", "foo@example.com"));
mail.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Excited Me", "bar@mydomain.com"));
mail.Subject = "Hello";
mail.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = @"Testing some awesomesauce!",
};

// Send it!
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

    client.Connect("smtp.mydomain.com", 587, false);
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
    client.Authenticate("postmaster@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME", "password");

    client.Send(mail);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

**Any pointer appreciated, thanks!**

Comment: Are you on a Corporate Network with Outlook installed or on your own PC?  Corporate Networks usually have port 587 blocked and use a proxy server to get to the email server.  So each user on a PC has Mail  properties in their login that specifies the email server.  You cannot use your own SMTP server because they are registered and use encryption to communicate and you do not have the encryption key.

Comment: Afraid this has nothing to do with. In a typical case the SMTP looks up the MX record and sends the email to that address. I'm not being blocked anywhere, I just can't specify a custom address to deliver the email to (as the MX isn't the right delivery location).

Comment: The FROM address and the account credentials have to be the same other wise the email gets rejected.